# How to use Stream, to write an efficient shuffling method

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have an `ArrayList` of `Residence` objects. Each `Residence` object has two fields, `type::String`, and `price::BigInteger`. I was wondering if there is an efficient way to restructure the list, in such a way, so no `Residence` object with the same `name` is next to each other. The goal is to write an efficient, shuffling method.

Comment: That's not a shuffle. You don't say a deck of cards is well shuffled because there are no cards of the same suit next to one another. Shuffle implies randomness. Randomness doesn't care what looks to humans "more random" than something else

Comment: Also, how is such an algorithm supposed to account for e.g. the case where all the names are the same? There is no possible result.

Comment: The assumption is that the data available has an adequate plethora of names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a `HashMap<String, Stack<Residence>>` and save the corresponding element for each type.
Then loop the `hashmap` through the keys in a Round Robin way and pop the item from the stack. Each item you get, you can add it to a new list.
Assuming your ArrayList of Residence is `residences`, the code should be something like this (Not tested, only for show the algorithm):

```
HashMap<String, Stak<Residence>> hm;
ArrayList<Residence> resultList = new ArrayList();

for (Residence r : residences) {              
    hm.put(r.type, r);
}

boolean exist = true;
while(exist) {
    exist = false;
    for(Map.Entry m : hm.entrySet()){    
        if(!m.getValue().isEmpty()) {
            exist = true;
            resultList.add(m.getValue().pop());
        }      
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is actually quite helpful.
Is it possible to modify it so from each Stack, the Residence object with the lowest price value, is returned?

Comment: @Dc235 Yes, the algorithm can be modified to return always the `Residence` with lowest price. You can replace the Stack by a Priority Queue, the priority should be the price value. You are welcome.